# How can I center a widget in python tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So basically I made this program that when you run it, it would open a form where you can fill out text entry and etc, but I want to centre the text entries in the form and I tried the anchor method but it just made it disappear.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("150x50+680+350")

def FormSubmission():
    global button_start
    root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
    tk.Label(root, text="First Name:").grid(row=0)  
    e1 = tk.Entry(root) 
    e1.grid(row=0, column=1) 
    tk.Label(root, text="Last Name:").grid(row=1) 
    e2 = tk.Entry(root)
    e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
    button_start.place_forget()


button_start = tk.Button(root, text="Start", height=3, width=20, command = FormSubmission)
button_start.place(x = 0, y = 10)
button_exit = tk.Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
button_exit.place(x=1506, y=0)

root.mainloop()
```

I want to anchor the text entry and the label next to them etc

Comment: btw generally it isn't a good idea to mix geometry managers like `.place` and `.grid`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you want. Do you want the whole form centred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the widgets to be cantered in a separate frame,

```py
frame=tk.Frame(root)
tk.Label(frame, text="First Name:").grid(row=0)  
e1 = tk.Entry(frame) 
e1.grid(row=0, column=1) 
tk.Label(frame, text="Last Name:").grid(row=1) 
e2 = tk.Entry(frame)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

and then use any of the below methods to center it

- Using `pack`

  ```
  frame.pack(anchor='center',expand=True)
  ```
- Using `grid`

  ```
  frame.grid()
  root.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
  root.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
  ```

The above methods would work to center the frame if that is the only widget in the parent that has been placed using `pack`/`grid` respectively, otherwise you will have to make changes accordingly.

- Using `place`

  ```
  frame.place(relx=.5,rely=.5,anchor='center')
  ```

This would center the widget in the parent, overlapping the widgets (if any) that are present below.